# Spark - Pass Generic Array to GenericRowWithSchema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am trying to build a Spark utility that reads data from an HBase table and writes to a Hive table. The pre-requisite here is that all columns are of type String.

My approach here is to read the Hbase table in an `RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)]`, then convert it to `RDD[GenericRowWithSchema]` and then to a Spark dataframe. I'm fine with the first part, but am facing problems with the second one. My code looks something like this

```
def parseRow(result: Result, hiveColumns: Array[String], tableSchema: StructType):  = {

  val rowKey = Bytes.toString(result.getRow)
  val cfDataBytes = Bytes.toBytes("cf")

  val colArray = hiveColumns.map(col => Bytes.toString(result.getValue(cfDataBytes, Bytes.toBytes(col))))

  new GenericRowWithSchema(colArray, tableSchema)

}
```

I get an error while declaring the `parseRow` function

```
error:Type mismatch
found: Array[String]
required: Array[Any]

Note: String <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_<:Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  new GenericRowWithSchema(colArray, tableSchema)
                           ^
```

I'm using the function as follows

```
val tableName = "xyz" // This will be an arg that is passed to the job
val hiveColumns: Array[String] = spark.table(tableName)

val tableSchema: StructType = StructType(hiveColumns.map(colName => StructField(colName, DataTypes.StringType, false)))

val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create
val scan: Scan = new Scan

hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "hbaseSchema:hbaseTable")
hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, TableMapReduceUtil.converScanToString(scan))

val hbaseRDD: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConfig, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])

import spark.implicits._

val resultRDD: RDD[Result] = hbaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)

val finalRDD: RDD[GenericRowWithSchema] = resultRDD.map(result => parseRow(result, hiveColumns, tableSchema))
```

How do I wrap the elements of Array[String] in Array[Any], so it's acceptable by the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

We just need to widen `Array[String]` to `Array[Any]` as follows

```
new GenericRowWithSchema(colArray.toArray, tableSchema)
```